# Thread inside a service, or service inside a thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I have a question about services: What would be better, create a thread within a service, or service within a thread?

The question comes because I am implementing an error reporter for my application, so that when the application fails it sends me a report with what has happened. My idea is a notification when an error occurs from here show activity Activity and creates a thread to retry delivery until it succeeds or reaches a minimum number of attempts.

Remaking the question, how is the system least likely to remove my process (if out of memory): With a thread within a service, or service within a thread?

I think the best is the first choice, but I saw a code in the same android people, here:

(line 640)
[code from google to keep alive a thread??](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/contacts/ui/EditContactActivity.java;h=3e248ea93dc8b17a0d66306aaade9ea398c32408;hb=HEAD)

Where they use the second. What do you think about it?

I don't need an AsyncTask, because I don't need to interact with the UI thread, I'm not showing anything at this point to the user.

Comment: Could you reformulate the part "My idea is a notification when an error occurs from here show activity Activity and creates a thread to retry delivery until it succeeds or reaches a minimum number of attempts."? You have an activity called `Activity`? And it creates the thread to retry?

Comment: of course, my idea is to send a notification to the user, and when he/she clicks on it, show an activity with two buttons (send and cancel). If the user clicks "send" now i'm starting a thread that tries to send errordata to a server, and in case of fail sleeps 30 minutes and try again, a maximum of 6 retries

Comment: You say you don't need an AsyncTask becouse you is not showing anything to the user at that point. So I imagine it's a background task that will not freeze the GUI, right? Just confirming..

Comment: As far as I know, Android will handles better a service then a thread. So a thread inside a service would be better.. But I would like someone to confirm that.

Answer (score 5):

Create your worker thread inside the service.

Comment: You gave an answer.. But is there any advantage, at all?

Comment: You usually create a service to perform background work, outside the life cycle of your activity. So the advantage is a service is not bound to the activity life cycle and its execution can span multiple activities.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I solved it by creating a service that creates a notification, and this notification generates an activity (when clicked) that launches a thread. I found this is the most stable combination, a bit embarrasing but works fine that is what i want!

thanks again and regards!